# Using the cut function to bin a numeric column creates NAN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

I'm trying to bin values in a panda's data frame column that is floar64  (min=0.000000, max=48.100000). The data originally doesn't have any missing/NAN values, but after binning, there are now NAN values in addition to the labels/categories.
How did this happen? And if anyone can help me how to resolve this.

```
bins = [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 50.0]
labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
df['Distance'] = pd.cut(df['Distance'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
df.Distance.unique()
```

The output is:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', NaN]
Categories (4, object): ['1' < '2' < '3' < '4']
```

Comment: Did your data has `Nan`? Also, you might want to pass `include_lowest=True` as `0` would yield `NaN` as well. For example , try `pd.cut(bins, bins, labels=labels)`...

Comment: @QuangHoang That was it! Adding include_lowest=True resolved this. Thanks.